# Python Mako Template empty output

Tags: python, mako

Ran into this today; posting for future generations

If you're rendering a mako template which defines a

```
<%block name="body" />
```

in it, and you're getting an empty string as output

Answer (score 0):

Odds are it's because your block is conflicting with mako's internal variables.  Try renaming it to something else and rendering it again